# Unable to enforce exit node country (ubuntu)?

Tags: exit-relays, ubuntu

I tried to enforce Tor to use an exit node in The Netherlands, by adding the following lines to /etc/tor/torrc:
ExitNodes {NL}
StrictNodes 1

After editing, I did 
sudo service tor restart

However, when using the Tor browser, I end up with an exit node in a random country. Any help is appreciated...

Comment: The Tor Browser uses its own instance of Tor. You need to change the browser's torrc file.

Comment: Specifically `tor-browser_en-US/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Tor/torrc`